# How to get import options in vscode similar to pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, visual-studio-code

In Pycharm I press **ALT + Enter** hotkey to get suggestion and import what I need.
This feature is very helpful.

[image]

How should I do the same in Visual Studio Code

[image]

Comment: if you have PROBLEMS where there is no Quick Action for you can make them yourself with [My Code Actions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.my-code-actions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The Solution

*You need an extension called [Pylance](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance)*

Tap the highlighted text, press `Ctrl` & `.`

It will tell you possible imports to solve it.

However, I don't think it takes into account the function after it nor checks whether the following function or variable is in the module